# WPF Animation with Collision Detection: How to Implement?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to create an animation where a car drives on a road, waits for a train to pass, and then continues. However, I'm having trouble finding information on how to implement this. Additionally, I want the cars to drive in a 'row,' but currently, they are driving through each other. Is this even possible?

```
namespace Symulator_ruchu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        Random r = new Random();
        IEnumerable<PathFigure> colle;

        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        DispatcherTimer train = new DispatcherTimer();
     
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispTimer_tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
            train.Tick += new EventHandler(train_tick);
            train.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            train.Start();
        }

        private void train_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Path car = new Path
            {
                Name = "AnimatedMatrixTrain",
                Fill = Train.Fill,
                Data = new RectangleGeometry
                {

                    Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 55, 270)
                },
                LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform
                {
                    Angle = 90
                },
                RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform
                {

                    Matrix = new Matrix
                    {
                        OffsetX = 100,
                        OffsetY = 100
                    }
                }

            };

            MatrixAnimationUsingPath maup = new MatrixAnimationUsingPath
            {
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.Next(5, 10)),
                DoesRotateWithTangent = true,
                AutoReverse = false,
                PathGeometry = new PathGeometry
                {
                    Figures = PathFigureCollection.Parse("M 745,900 L 745,0")
                }
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(maup, car);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(maup, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(MatrixTransform.Matrix)"));

            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(maup);

            //Canvas.SetTop(car, r.Next(1, 500));
            //Canvas.SetLeft(car, r.Next(1, 500));

            storyboard.Begin(car);

            Canv.Children.Add(car);
        }

        private void dispTimer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Path car = new Path
            {
                Name = "AnimatedMatrixCar",
                Fill = Car.Fill,
                Data = new RectangleGeometry
                {
                    
                   Rect = new Rect(0,0,60,30)
                },
                LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform
                {
                    Angle = 180
                },
                RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform
                {
                    
                    Matrix = new Matrix
                    {
                        OffsetX = 100,
                        OffsetY = 100
                    }
                }

            };

           
            MatrixAnimationUsingPath maup = new MatrixAnimationUsingPath
            {
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.Next(5,10)),
                DoesRotateWithTangent = true,
                AutoReverse = false,
                PathGeometry = new PathGeometry
                {
                    Figures = PathFigureCollection.Parse("m 10,286 h 800 c 130,10  190, 200 -105, 180 h -450 c -160,10 -200,250 -35,290 H 1200")
                }
            };

          
            Storyboard.SetTarget(maup, car);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(maup, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(MatrixTransform.Matrix)"));

            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(maup);

            //Canvas.SetTop(car, r.Next(1, 500));
            //Canvas.SetLeft(car, r.Next(1, 500));

            storyboard.Begin(car);

            Canv.Children.Add(car);

          
        }
    }
```

Here is how WPF window looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPSoM.png)

Comment: I realised this morning I missed a couple of things out my explanation so I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use collision detection in an animation. You'd have to write your own code moved the car pixel by pixel. You could then use a distance calculation between some calculated edge point of your rectangle and anything else.
That's all possible but you'd be calculating angle of rotation yourself. Fair bit of fiddly work and it might not even be so smooth once you're finished.

I'd go with storyboard and animations.

Some trial and error will be necessary for this in order for the train to pass just after a car stops.

Use a storyboard and at least two matrix animations within that.

Each animation can have a begin time and duration. The first animation should have no begin time, you want that to start straight away.
You might want one of the easout easing functions so it slows down as it nears the crossing.

The second animation should have a begin time which makes it start up again after the train has passed. This time with an ease in easing function so it accelerates up to speed.

You will need to split your path geometry into two parts. Up to the crossing and then from the crossing to end of road. You could use inkscape or manually find where your crossing is using the points in the geometry.

You will apply this to your first car.
Off it goes.

Use async await to introduce a delay. Then repeat using your storyboard with the second car. It will of course do the same as the first one but start a bit later, giving a gap.

There is a bit of a complication though. Maybe you want your second car to stop behind the first.
That means you need two different geometries with the second ending earlier.

Not sure if you have your geometries.

I would use inkscape to draw the path. It's free. You could import your base picture, add a layer and draw a vectorin the new layer. That has line start and and nodes and curve handle nodes. You can drag the nodes and add more. There's a bit of a learning curve but it'll be fairly easy to do your neat line. Then select your line and save as xaml. You'll get a file with a path in it, and your geometry. Extra nodes for a second and third car stop position.

Are your cars looking ok with the matrix animation? I wrote a facing converter to rotate moving (infantry or cavalry) columns so they face the direction they are moving in.